# save integration test mapping of appsettings.json on moving from xproj,porject.json to csproj

Tags: asp.net-core, migration, csproj, .xproj

I am trying to migrate my sln from xproj+project.json to csproj.
I had on my project.json for my integration test project:

```
"buildOptions": {
"copyToOutput": {
  "mappings": {
    "appsettings.json": "../../src/WebApp/appsettings.json",
    "appsettings.testing.json": "../../src/WebApp/appsettings.testing.json"
  }
 }
}
```

when I opened the .sln with visual studio 2017 it automatically converted to:

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Update="..\..\src\WebApp\appsettings.testing.json">
  <Link>appsettings.testing.json</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Update="..\..\src\WebApp\appsettings.json">
  <Link>appsettings.json</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

but now the integration tests stopped working since it not find the appsettings.json file.
it throws:

> Error Message:
>    System.IO.FileNotFoundException : The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Work\billing-app\test\IntegrationTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\appsettings.json'.

how can I fix it so it'll continue to copy the real configuration file to the integration test project? 10x!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to add to my web project csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Update="appsettings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

and it works.

(the mentioned lines above of integrationTest project csproj can be deleted)